# Characterization of uniformly convergent sequence of functions

Tags: limits-and-convergence

Let $f_n$ a sequence of continuos function from a metric space $(X,d)$ itself. If $f_n$ converge uniformly to a function $f $  and $\varphi$ is  real valued  uniformly continuos function defined on $X$, then $\varphi\circ f_n$ converge to $\varphi\circ f$ uniformly.

Proof: As $\varphi $ is uniformly continuos, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $ \delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $\vert \varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\vert<\epsilon$. As $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$, there exists $n_0\geq 1$ such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $d(f_n(x),f(x))<\delta$ for all $x\in X$. Thus, for $n\geq n_0$ we have $ \vert \varphi(f_n(x))-\varphi(f(x))\vert< \epsilon $, concluiding that $\varphi\circ f_n$ converge to $\varphi\circ f$ uniformly.

**Question**: Conversely, if $\varphi\circ f_n$ converge uniformly to $\varphi\circ f$ for all real valued uniformly continuos function $\varphi$ defined on $X$, then $f_n$ converge uniformly to f?

Is easy to show that $f_n$ converge to $f$ pointwise. Indeed,  for fixed $x$, the function $\delta(y)=d(y,f(x))$ is uniformly continuos. Then, as, in particular, $\delta \circ f_n(x)$ converge to $\delta \circ f(x)$, we have that $f_n(x)$ converge to $f(x)$.